# JDOM getChildren() returns empty list

Tags: java, xml, jdom

this is my xml:

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF_8" standalone="yes"?>
<StoreMessage xmlns="http://www.xxx.com/feed">
    <billingDetail>
        <billingDetailId>987</billingDetailId>       
        <contextId>0</contextId>
        <userId>
            <pan>F0F8DJH348DJ</pan>
            <contractSerialNumber>46446</contractSerialNumber>            
        </userId>            
        <declaredVehicleClass>A</declaredVehicleClass>
    </billingDetail>
    <billingDetail>
        <billingDetailId>543</billingDetailId>       
        <contextId>0</contextId>
        <userId>
            <pan>F0F854534534348DJ</pan>
            <contractSerialNumber>4666546446</contractSerialNumber>            
        </userId>            
        <declaredVehicleClass>C</declaredVehicleClass>
    </billingDetail>
</StoreMessage>
```

With JDOM parser i want to get all `<billingDetail>` xml nodes from it.

my code:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
try {
    Reader in = new StringReader(xmlAsString);
    Document document = (Document)builder.build(in);
    Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
    List<?> list = rootNode.getChildren("billingDetail");

    XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();
        outp.setFormat(Format.getCompactFormat());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Element node = (Element)list.get(i);

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            outp.output(node.getContent(), sw);
            StringBuffer sb = sw.getBuffer();

            String text = sb.toString();
            xmlRecords.add(sb.toString());
        }

} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
} catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
    jdomex.printStackTrace();
}
```

but i never get as output xml node as string like:

```
<billingDetail>
    <billingDetailId>987</billingDetailId>       
    <contextId>0</contextId>
    <userId>
        <pan>F0F8DJH348DJ</pan>
        <contractSerialNumber>46446</contractSerialNumber>            
    </userId>            
    <declaredVehicleClass>A</declaredVehicleClass>
</billingDetail>
```

what i am doing wrong? How can i get this output with JDOM parser?

EDIT

And why if XML start with

`<StoreMessage>` instead like `<StoreMessage xmlns="http://www.xxx.com/MediationFeed">`

then works? How is this possible?

Comment: You say "you never get expected output". What do you get instead?

Comment: you can check this , http://projectwownow.blogspot.in/2008/08/java-node-to-string-conversion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are two versions of the getChildren method:

java.util.List  getChildren(java.lang.String name) 
          This returns a List of all the child elements nested directly (one level deep) within this element with the given local name and belonging to no namespace, returned as Element objects.

and

java.util.List getChildren(java.lang.String name, Namespace ns) 
          This returns a List of all the child elements nested directly (one level deep) within this element with the given local name and belonging to the given Namespace, returned as Element objects.

The first one doesn't find your node if it belongs to a namespace, you should use the second one.